# Populating DatagridView from a Foreach loop through a DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have used a database to populate Data-grids on many occasions.
However, in this instance, i can't seem to get the desired result.
I am trying to display only the people who have a birthday on the day.
i already have the dates, and the Birthday, but i can't seem to get teh rows to add to the datagridview.

here is how far i have got.  But he "BirthdayGrdVw.DataSource" i can't seem to figure out.

i have been googling for 2 days.

I am new to this, and would really appreciate some assistance.

```
    private void Tasks_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Clients = Controller.DBQueries.GetPolicyList();
        if(Clients != null)
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in Clients.Rows)
            {
                string ClientID = Clients.Rows[0]["ClientID"].ToString();
                DateTime Birthdate = Controller.GetBirthdate(ClientID);
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;            
                if (Birthdate.Day == now.Day && Birthdate.Month == now.Month)
                {

                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. for the edit.

Comment: There is no code that adds to a DataGridView in what you have posted.

Comment: `Clients = Controller.DBQueries.GetPolicyList();`

I think you are missing something here, what is `Clients` ?

Comment: Hi there.  The DataTable is already populated, through my DataBaseAccess and Query.  The DataTable is called Clients.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be things left out you your code, but without all of the information here is what I suggest you try if you are sure that your datatable has been populated.

Add a bindingsource object to your Windows Form by dragging it from the toolbox onto the form.

Set the it will be called bindingsource1. Set it's DataSource to the datatable like this:

```
 BindingSource1.DataSource = "your data table name here";
```

And then set the DataGridView's DataSource to bindingsource1.

```
 "Your DataGridView".DataSource = BindingSource1;
```

Or if you don't need some of the extra functionality that a BindingSource provides like "Filter" etc... You could bind the datatable directly to the DataGridView like:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = "your data table name here";
```

Comment: The reason i left out the gridview datasource is because i can't get it to populate.  here is an example of one of the attempts.  BirthdayGrdVw.DataSource = Clients.Rows;

Comment: What type of object is Clients? It has a Rows property, is it not a Datatable?

Answer (score 0):

If Clients is a DataTable and you know what filtering you want to apply then why not use Filter on datatable as :

```
DataView dv = new DataView(Clients);
dv.RowFilter = "month(of your Birthday Col)="+now.Month+" and day(of your BirthDay Col)="+now.Day;

yourGridView.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
yourGridView.DataBind();
```

instead of all Foreach loop and all?